# Post request using CURL PHP returning error 400? Systatically Wrong Request

Tags: php, spring, rest, spring-mvc, curl

I am doing a post request using cUrl and PHP, the code is mentioned below

```
<?php            
 $data = array("employeeAuth" => array("employeeNumber" => "376819"));
 $data_post = json_encode($data);
 echo $data_post;
 $cSession = curl_init('http://10.40.4.170:80/xxxxxx/eeee/zzzz/kkkk');
 curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
 curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_post);
 curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 curl_setopt($cSession,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array(
            "Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Content-Length:". strlen($data_string)
           ));
 $result=curl_exec($cSession);
 curl_close($cSession);
 echo $result;
?>
```

After this code runs I get Error 400 from the server as response stating that the request is Syntactically wrong. Please let me know If I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `Content-Length` based on `$data_string`, but I think you meant `$data_post` since `$data_string` isn't defined anywhere.  But, try removing the `Content-Length` entry all together, CURL will calculate and include it for you.  Also, include a space after the colon in each header.

Comment: How can I be so careless :( :( .... Thanks a ton Jake...!! This was absolutely that was messed up. Kudos! :)